# Recursion inside let function

Tags: recursion, clojure, let

I'm confused as to how def and let bind variables differently. Can someone explain to me why this works:

```clj
(def leven
  (memoize
   (fn [x y]
     (cond (empty? x) (count y)
           (empty? y) (count x)
           :else (min (+ (leven (rest x) y) 1)
                      (+ (leven x (rest y)) 1)
                      (+ (leven (rest x) (rest y)) (if (= (first x) (first y)) 0 1)))))))
```

But when I try to declare the function as let it fails to compile:

```clj
(def leven
  (let [l (memoize (fn [x y]
                     (cond (empty? x) (count y)
                           (empty? y) (count x)
                           :else (min (+ (l (rest x) y) 1)
                                      (+ (l x (rest y)) 1)
                                      (+ (l (rest x) (rest y)) (if (= (first x) (first y)) 0 1))))))]
    (l x y)))
```

EDIT: This works, using the technique showed by Ankur.

```clj
(defn leven [x y]
  (let [l (memoize (fn [f x y]
                     (cond (empty? x) (count y)
                           (empty? y) (count x)
                           :else (min (+ (f f (rest x) y) 1)
                                      (+ (f f x (rest y)) 1)
                                      (+ (f f (rest x) (rest y)) (if (= (first x) (first y)) 0 1))))))
        magic (partial l l)]
    (magic x y)))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below is such an example to do what you have asked for. I am using factorial just for the sake of simplicity and added println in factorial to make sure the memoization is working fine

```
(let [fact (memoize (fn [f x] 
                       (println (str "Called for " x))
                       (if (<= x 1) 1 (* x  (f f (- x 1))))))
      magic (partial fact fact)] 
     (magic 10)
     (magic 11))
```

First calculate factorial of 10 and then 11 in which case it should not again call factorial for 10 till 1 as that has been memoized.

```
Called for 10
Called for 9
Called for 8
Called for 7
Called for 6
Called for 5
Called for 4
Called for 3
Called for 2
Called for 1
Called for 11
39916800
```

Comment: Very interesting. So you are basically just passing in the function as an argument so the compiler doesn't get confused about it not being defined. I can't try this out now, but I'm going to try this approach later.

Answer (score 6):

The `let` form binds names sequentially so in your second function definition the name `l` doesn't exist when you try to refer to it. You can either use `letfn` (with some minor mods) or give the defined function a name and instead refer to that instead, like so:

```
(def leven  
  (let [l (memoize (fn SOME-NAME [x y]
    (cond 
      (empty? x) (count y)
      (empty? y) (count x)
      :else (min (+ (SOME-NAME (rest x) y) 1)
                 (+ (SOME-NAME x (rest y)) 1)
                 (+ (SOME-NAME (rest x) (rest y)) (if (= (first x) (first y)) 0 1))))))]
l))
```

As you might notice I change the return from the `let` to be `l` itself since that is what you want `leven` bound to.  The `(l x y)` was problematic because it referred to bindings only local to the function and not accessible to the `let`.

Comment: Doesn't the function SOME-NAME lose the benefits of memoize when used like that? Don't you need to call the function memoize returns, or is it not possible to have a recursive memoized function in a let statement?

Comment: @onit The definition `leven` can be revised to gain the benefits of memoization by moving `SOME-NAME` in as the first argument: `(fn [SOME-NAME x y]`, and then by also replacing calls to `SOME-NAME` to `(SOME-NAME SOME-NAME ...)` and finally by replacing the return value `l` to be `(partial l l)`.